# JSF viewAction called twice

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, managed-bean

I have a simple JSF project where I use `<f:viewaction action="#{backingBean.init}"/>` and the backing bean is being constructed twice. I trace out the session id and I get different session ids for each call.

index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{backingBean.init}"/>
</f:metadata>
<h:body>
<h:outputLabel value="#{backingBean.text}"/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

BackingBean.java

```
package com.test.bean;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class BackingBean {

    public BackingBean() {
        System.out.println("Constructor called");
    }

    public void init() {
        FacesContext fCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        String sessionId = fCtx.getExternalContext().getSessionId(false);
        System.out.println("Init called - session id: "+sessionId);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return "Some text";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0                 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>PrerenderViewTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

</faces-config>
```

I have tried other methods of calling the `init()` like using the `@PostConstruct` annotation or `<f:event type="prerenderview" listener="#{backingBean.init}"/>` but I get the same results. The init method is always called twice the first time when I access the page. On subsequent calls it is only called once.

Comment: Try making your backing bean `Serializable`

Comment: I have tried that and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: is the init() method called for both beans?

Comment: There has to be something configured incorrectly as `@PostConstruct` shouldn't be called more than once per session. Are the sessionIds you print out the same? What server are you running on? Are you sure the dependencies you're loading are compatible?

Comment: The session ids are different. I am running Tomcat 8.0.9

Comment: I just tried running on Tomcat 7 and got the same results

Comment: I did some poking around and I couldn't find any clear consensus on what dependencies you need to include to run JSF on Tomcat. You might consider using TomEE (http://tomee.apache.org/downloads.html) since that has the web profile bits integrated and ready to go. You could also try JBoss or Glassfish. That way you're only debugging your code and not your configuration as well.

Comment: How many GET requests do you find in your browser console, that result in two JSESSION_IDs being generated? A new id should be generated only on request. That could be as a result of your browser not being able to provide a previous JSESSION_ID cookie on a second request, but first, you need to establish that two requests are being initiated somehow

Comment: I have now deployed on GlassFish 4.0.0 and now the session id is always the same but the init method is called six times when I use the <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{backingBean.init}"/> and three times when I use @PostConstruct.

Comment: I made a mistake. The init() method is called 3 times when I use the preRenderView event.

Comment: I have also tried deploying on TomEE and the init() method is called 3 times and unlike GlassFish I get different session ids for each call.